# if statement not work with multiple isset value check

Tags: php

Above code is not working in core php

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['standBy']) AND !isset($_SESSION['auemail'])){
    header("Location:../../index.php"); die;
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what is happening when you execute the code.
Does it generate an error, do nothing, a wrong redirect etc.

Comment: Not working is not a proper description of your problem. Add error logs and additional debug info so the people here can understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&&` as an 'AND' comparator.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['standBy']) && !isset($_SESSION['auemail'])){
    header("Location:../../index.php"); 
    die();
}
```

Comment: you can use [and](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) operator also die is an function so should be called like this `die()`

Comment: You can use `and`, but is has a lower precedence compared to `&&`, but not in this case. It is something to keep in mind though.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses for `die`

Answer (score 0):

Your code above is checking if session has a "standBy" by variable and "auemail" isn't in the  session variable.

So the condition would be *true* if thats the case you really want.

However i would advice you substitute the "AND" for "&&" so it becomes

```
if (isset($_SESSION['standBy']) && !isset($_SESSION['auemail'])){
    header("Location:../../index.php");
 die();
}
```